# Make an iPhone property read-only in iOS objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

OK basically I have a class in an iPhone app where I want it to some read only propertys. Meaning that the owning class can read and write the property, but other objects can only read it.  I try the "readonly" option when I declare the property, but then my class can't even write it.  What use is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not too inconvenient, just use the ivar or "backing" variable in your class to modify the value.  Like this:

In your .h file:

```
@interface ClassName

@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSInteger readOnlyValue;

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
@implementation ClassName

@synthesize readOnlyValue = _readOnlyValue;



_readOnlyValue = 42;

@end
```

Comment: This is simplified, because you use primitive type. What about retain release, if readOnlyValue would be an Object e.g UILabel?

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume you wanted to create a property called `foo`, an `int`, in your class `YourClass`.

Do this in your interface (.h) file:

```
@property(readonly) int foo;
```

Then in your implementation (.m) file, set up a class extension where you can re-define your property.

```
@interface YourClass()

@property(readwrite) int foo;

@end
```

This results in the property being `readonly` publicly, but `readwrite` privately.

Then, of course, you synthesize `foo` in your implementation that follows.

```
@synthesize foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could go the route of direct iVar access as described in other answers, a better solution is typically to use class extensions.  They were designed exactly to solve this problem and, by using them, you can easily refactor your code later to expose the `readwrite` definition of the `@property` to other classes in your app without exposing it to all classes.

I wrote up a [detailed explanation](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/) a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own setter in the .m class or synteshize as:
foo = _foo; so you can call _foo (private variable) internally

Answer (score 0):

On further reflection, the easiest way to achieve this is to add a normal property in a class extension, then declare just the getter in the header. E.g.

Interface:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

- (NSString *)someString;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;
@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize someString;

@end
```

You'll be able to get and set, using dot notation or otherwise, and directly access the `someString` instance variable within the class, and everyone that has sight of the interface will be able to get, using dot notation or otherwise.